# What is a good layout to render this design in Java?

Tags: java, swing, layout, jframe, jpanel

I'm new to Java.  I'm making a multiplayer Tic-Tac-Toe game as a test.  For the main menu, I'd love a layout that looked like this:
[image: Ideal layout]

The problem is, I have no idea how to make that.  I have a `JFrame` with all the content ready (the buttons and such), but everything appears completely out of location.  I've tried `BoxLayout`, `GridLayout`, `FlowLayout`, and a few others, with no results.  I've had a headache over this all day, and any help would be appreciated.

So, if you have any recommended layouts, or any tips to get this working, that'd be great :)

Comment: I'd use a [nested layout](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556).

Comment: [GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a nested layout that looked something like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8MGo.png]

`GridBagLayout` is useful for a more flexible layout, and `BoxLayout` for lining up a bunch of stuff.